# One sub site is slow while all others load fine, same theme & plugins

Tags: plugins, multisite, pages, performance

I have one sub site that is running slow and takes over a minute to load. It times out all the sites like pagespeed insights or pingdom.
This is the site:
http://www.evantage360.com/jleech

I don't want to delete all my plugins since there are over 100 other users so cloned the site & deleted all my unused plugins, ran wp-sweep to clean the database & setup the site on cloudfare. Oh and I ran smushit pro on the sites images.
That seemed so speed things up:
http://www.evantageaz.com/jleech

Went back & did the same on my orig site but no luck, still slow page loads and doing anything in admin takes a few minutes to load. Updated WordPress & the network and optimized the database.

How can I determine what is slowing my page or what its looking for that it is not finding? Don't see any anything in the server error logs.

The server is godaddy dedicated and the load is very low.

Its just the one site out of over 100 that won't load?

Tried a couple freelancers I use but they couldn't locate or solve the issue.

Since my duplicated site seems to run at normal speed, should I try copying the tables for that one sub site from that DB to my original sites DB?

I ran the plugin profiler and it shows its taking 536 to load a plugin that I have already removed?

thanks!
-George

Comment: Here is the profiler screenshot:  http://imgur.com/TXHtHG3

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you actually deleted the plugin and did not just disable it.

Assuming that the plugin was deleted, one of the following could cause this:

---

**Bad Cron Jobs**

Some plugins will create cron jobs and not remove them when the plugin is disabled or deleted.

These can easily slow sites down if set up badly.

Check to see if the plugin created cron jobs and remove any found.

Do a quick search on this site for removing cron jobs and you will find what you need to track them down and remove them.

---

**Extra Options**

Check for theme options and post_meta options created by the plugin and delete them.

I doubt that this is the main problem as you have to add tons of options to really slow things down ... but some plugins do so.

---

I cannot think of a lot of other things that could cause this kind of problem. Hopefully someone else can chime in here.

Comment: I have it solved.
I had duplicated the site, removed some plugins and used a plugin to clean the DB which I had never done before. Something worked, don't know what but the site was good.  Tried the same at orig site with no luck, orig site still slow.

Then I copied all tables from the dupe site to orig site & everything is fine.